# How can i get help for integer method in python3

Tags: python-3.x

If i want to get the information about string's methods i write

```
help('blabla'.islower())
```

But how can i get the information about methods of integers. See the examples below

```
help((1).numerator())
```

The error is

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

or for any other method

Comment: try `help(int.numerator)`

Answer (score 1):

`help(int.numerator)`

The canonical format for help on a classmethod would be `help(cls.method)`. `help` takes objects, classes, or functions, and returns the documentation for those respectively. To get docs for a method, pass in that method (`int.numerator` is an example of such a method)

Additionally if you insist on wanting to pass in an integer object:

```
a = 1

help(a.numerator)
```